# Multi Recurrence Relations

Tags: combinatorics, recurrence-relations

Solve the following recurrence relation:

$$a_n = 3a_{n-2}+2a_{n-3} + 81n^2(2)^n+32(3)^n+4n+4$$

Workings:

$a_n^{(h)} = 3a_{n-2}^{(h)}+2a_{n-3}^{(h)}$

$ch(x) = x^3 + 3x^2 + 2x$

$ch(x) = x(x+1)(x+2)$

$(1) a_n = 3a_{n-2} + 2a_{n-3} + 81n^2(2)^n$

$(2) a_n = 3a_{n-2} + 2a_{n-3} + 32(3)^n$

$(3) a_n = 3a_{n-2} + 2a_{n-3} + 4n + 4$

$(1) a_n^{(p_1)} = (c_1n^2 + c_2n +c)(2)^n$

$(c_1n^2 + c_2n +c)(2)^n = 3(c_1(n^2-2)+c_2(n-2)+c_3)2^{n-2} + 2(c_1(n^2-3)+c_2(n-3)+c_3)2^{n-3} + 81n^22^n$

$8(c_1n^2+c_2n+c_3) = 6(c_1(n^2-2)+c_2(n-2)+c_3) + 2(c_1(n^2-3)+c_2(n-3)+c_3) + 648n^2$

$n^2: 8c_1 = 6c_1 + 2c_1 + 648$

$n: 8c_2 = 6c_1 + 2c_2$

$1: 8c_3 = -12c_1 -12c_2 + 6c_3 - 6c_1 - 6c_2 + 2c_3$

Now I'm stuck and don't sure what to do. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> $$a_n = 3a_{n-2}+2a_{n-3} + 81n^2(2)^n+32(3)^n+4n+4$$

This might not be explicitly solvable, due to the unsolvability of quintics.  But a general approach is "write the linear parts on one side of the equation, and the non linear parts on the other, then increment":

$$\begin{align}
%
a_{n}        -  3 ~ a_{n  -  2}  -  2 ~ a_{n  -  3} &=    81 ~ n^2 ~ 2^n  +                                          32 ~ 3^n  +  4 ~ n  +  4  \\
%
a_{n  +  1}  -  3 ~ a_{n  -  1}  -  2 ~ a_{n  -  2} &=   162 ~ n^2 ~ 2^n  +    324 ~ n ~ 2^n  +     162 ~ 2^n  +     96 ~ 3^n  +  4 ~ n  +  8   \\
%
a_{n  +  2}  -  3 ~ a_{n}        -  2 ~ a_{n  -  1} &=   324 ~ n^2 ~ 2^n  +   1296 ~ n ~ 2^n  +    1296 ~ 2^n  +    288 ~ 3^n  +  4 ~ n  +  12   \\
%
a_{n  +  3}  -  3 ~ a_{n  +  1}  -  2 ~ a_{n}       &=   648 ~ n^2 ~ 2^n  +   3888 ~ n ~ 2^n  +    5832 ~ 2^n  +    864 ~ 3^n  +  4 ~ n  +  16    \\
%
a_{n  +  4}  -  3 ~ a_{n  +  2}  -  2 ~ a_{n  +  1} &=  1296 ~ n^2 ~ 2^n  +  10368 ~ n ~ 2^n  +   20736 ~ 2^n  +   2592 ~ 3^n  +  4 ~ n  +  20     \\
%
a_{n  +  5}  -  3 ~ a_{n  +  3}  -  2 ~ a_{n  +  2} &=  2592 ~ n^2 ~ 2^n  +  25920 ~ n ~ 2^n  +   64800 ~ 2^n  +   7776 ~ 3^n  +  4 ~ n  +  24      \\
%
a_{n  +  6}  -  3 ~ a_{n  +  4}  -  2 ~ a_{n  +  3} &=  5184 ~ n^2 ~ 2^n  +  62208 ~ n ~ 2^n  +  186624 ~ 2^n  +  23328 ~ 3^n  +  4 ~ n  +  28       \\
%
\end{align}$$

Now the nonlinear side of the equations are composed of six coefficients:

$$\begin{cases}
n^2~2^n = u \\
n~2^n = v \\
2^n = w \\
3^n = x \\
n = y \\
1 = z \\
\end{cases}$$

$$\begin{align}
%
a_{n}        -  3 ~ a_{n  -  2}  -  2 ~ a_{n  -  3} &=    81 ~ u  +                                32 ~ x  +  4 ~ y  +  4 ~ z  \\
%
a_{n  +  1}  -  3 ~ a_{n  -  1}  -  2 ~ a_{n  -  2} &=   162 ~ u  +    324 ~ v  +    162 ~ w  +    96 ~ x  +  4 ~ y  +  8 ~ z   \\
%
a_{n  +  2}  -  3 ~ a_{n}        -  2 ~ a_{n  -  1} &=   324 ~ u  +   1296 ~ v  +   1296 ~ w  +   288 ~ x  +  4 ~ y  +  12 ~ z   \\
%
a_{n  +  3}  -  3 ~ a_{n  +  1}  -  2 ~ a_{n}       &=   648 ~ u  +   3888 ~ v  +   5832 ~ w  +   864 ~ x  +  4 ~ y  +  16 ~ z    \\
%
a_{n  +  4}  -  3 ~ a_{n  +  2}  -  2 ~ a_{n  +  1} &=  1296 ~ u  +  10368 ~ v  +  20736 ~ w  +  2592 ~ x  +  4 ~ y  +  20 ~ z     \\
%
a_{n  +  5}  -  3 ~ a_{n  +  3}  -  2 ~ a_{n  +  2} &=  2592 ~ u  +  25920 ~ v  +  64800 ~ w  +  7776 ~ x  +  4 ~ y  +  24 ~ z      \\
%
a_{n  +  6}  -  3 ~ a_{n  +  4}  -  2 ~ a_{n  +  3} &=  5184 ~ u  +  62208 ~ v  + 186624 ~ w  + 23328 ~ x  +  4 ~ y  +  28 ~ z       \\
\end{align}$$

Now the 6 variables can be canceled from the 7 linear equations, to form 1 equation:

$$a_{n  +  6}  -  11 ~ a_{n  +  5}  +  46 ~ a_{n  +  4}  -  82 ~ a_{n  +  3}  +  17 ~ a_{n  +  2}  +  149 ~ a_{n  +  1}  -  176 ~ a_{n}  -  8 ~ a_{n  -  1}  +  112 ~ a_{n  -  2}  -  48 ~ a_{n  -  3}  =  0$$

Which can be written in matrix form as:

$$
\begin{bmatrix} a_{n+9} \\ a_{n+8} \\ a_{n+7} \\ a_{n+6} \\ a_{n+5} \\ a_{n+4} \\ a_{n+3} \\ a_{n+2} \\ a_{n+1} \\ a_{n} \end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & -11 & 46 & -82 & 17 & 149 & -176 & -8 & 112 & -48 \\
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
\end{bmatrix}^n
\begin{bmatrix} a_{9} \\ a_{8} \\ a_{7} \\ a_{6} \\ a_{5} \\ a_{4} \\ a_{3} \\ a_{2} \\ a_{1} \\ a_{0} \end{bmatrix}$$

Comment: I've never seen this before so thank you! Turns out the roots of the characteristic equation are all integers $$A(x) = (x-1)^2 \, (x+1)^2 \, (x-2)^4 \, (x-3)$$ so you get a fairly nice expression for $a_n$. $$a_n = \gamma_1 + \gamma_2n \; + \; [\gamma_3 + \gamma_4n]\,(-1)^n \;  +  \;[\gamma_5 + \gamma_6n + \gamma_7n^2 + \gamma_8n^3]\,2^n \; + \; \gamma_9 3^n$$

Comment: @Drew Would you believe it, it's the first time I've seen this technique too.

Comment: @Drew Interesting....but I think your characteristic equation is missing an $x^{10}$ term.

Comment: It's just a [9th degree polynomial](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=factor+x%5E9+-+11*x%5E8+%2B46*x%5E7+-+82*x%5E6+%2B+17*x%5E5+%2B+149*x%5E4+-+176*x%5E3+-8*x%5E2%2B112*x+-48&h=1).

Comment: Actually, it's not too surprising that the roots are all integers. Another way to go about solving this is to solve the homogenous recurrence $a_n = 3a_{n-2} - 2a_{n-3}$ which has solutions of the form $a_n = \gamma_1 + \gamma_2 2^n$, and then look for particular solutions which mimic the nonlinear parts.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Meant to respond sooner but I lost power.

Comment: Whoops typo in my last comment. The homogenous part is $a_n - 3a_{n-2} - 2a_{n-3} = 0$ which has solutions $a_n = [\gamma_1 + \gamma_2n] (-1)^n + \gamma_3 2^n$, since the characteristic equation is $(x-2)(x+1)^2$.